# Symfony 2 - getEnvorinment() in Prod

Tags: symfony, environment-variables

I am trying to test what the code below would dump in my various environments (local, dev, qa, int). By adding `/app_dev.php/` and `/app_qa.php/` after the domain, I am able to determine that Symfony outputs 'dev' and 'qa' respectably. When I try `/app_prod.php/` to simulate my INT environment, I get a server error message.

I want to confirm that using the code below on a prod environment would dump 'prod'.

```
var_dump( $this->container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment() );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment()` will return the value of the first argument of AppKernel when the framework is loaded.

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

getEnvironment() returns prod

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('qa', false);
```

getEnvironment() returns qa